# HTML -- PHP to Email

Tags: php, html, multi-step

Not sure if I'm doing this right. Completely new to this stuff... I have a multistep form that I'm trying to get submitted to my email. The form has a set of buttons in each phase. I'd like the selected buttons to be sent to my email.

**HTML**:

```
<fieldset id="secondField">
    <h2 class="fs-title"> Select A Course</h2>
        <input type="button" name="course" class="next action-button" value="Math" />
        <input type="button" name="course" class="next action-button" value="Science" />
</fieldset>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
   // from the form
   $course = trim(strip_tags($_POST['course']));
   $count = trim(strip_tags($_POST['count']));

 // set here
   $subject = "Course Request";
   $to = 'email';

   $body = <<<HTML
 COURSE: $course
 PARTICIPANTS: $count
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input! I got this one solved by adding a hidden field that updated when the user clicked a button. Code below. Thanks again!

<fieldset id="Step">
<input type="input" name="count" value="" id="count">
<button type="button" onclick="changeCount(event);" value="6-10">6-10</button>
<button type="button" onclick="changeCount(event);" value="10-15">10-15</button>
<br>
</fieldset>
<script>
function changeCount(event) {
    document.getElementById("count").value = event.target.value;
}
</script>

Answer (score 0):

You should use a "select" html tag for this purpose. So the user can select his options and then submit the form with pressing one button :

```
<fieldset id="secondField">
    <h2 class="fs-title"> Select A Course</h2>
    <select name="course" class="next action-button">
        <option value="math">Math</option>
        <option value="science">Science</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Choose" />
</fieldset>
```

Then you can retrieve course value selected by the user :

```
$course = $_POST['course']); // Either "math" or "science" here
```

Answer (score 0):

use formaction attribute

```
<fieldset id="secondField">
    <h2 class="fs-title"> Select A Course</h2>
        <input type="submit" formaction="../next.php" name="course" class="next action-button" value="Math" />
        <input type="submit" formaction="../send.php" name="course" class="next action-button" value="Science" />
</fieldset>
```